# import values from PHP with JS for chart column

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have this code in javascript for chart column:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#grafic_column').highcharts({
    chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
    series: [{
      name: 'Population',
      data: [
        ['Shanghai', 23.7],
        ['Lagos', 16.1],
        ['Istanbul', 14.2]
      ]
    }]
  });
});
```

And this cod in php:

```html
<?php
$ar = array(
  ['Shanghai', 23.7],
  ['Lagos', 16.1],
  ['Istanbul', 14.2]
);
echo json_encode($ar);
?>
```

How do import the values results from php in `series.data:`? Thank you!

Comment: Is the JavaScript code being served from your php server?

Comment: `data: [
          <?php echo json_encode($ar); ?>
      ]` ?

Comment: @Sherif, I tried so: `data: [ <?php include'myfile.php'; echo json_encode($ar); ?> ],` and not work.

Comment: does `myfiles.php` contain your data? if so include it in the top of your script and assing the data content to $ar and just do `data: [ <?php echo json_encode($ar); ?> ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your PHP file is accessible with a server, you can just perform `$.get` to make an AJAX request to the file serving the data:

```
$(function () {
    $.get('/yourphpfile.php').then(function(data) {
        $('#grafic_column').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Population',
                data: data
            }]
        });
    })
});
```